# Passing exe to Python for all the files in directories

Tags: python, subprocess, sys

When I execute the command for individual files, it works. However it does not work, when I want to use it inside a loop. What could be the problem ?
from subprocess import call
import os, sys

```
rootdir = r'C:\\Users\\X\\Desktop\\hump'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".ply"):            
            nf = file.replace('.ply', '.txt')
            os.system("C:\\Users\\X\\Desktop\\fftw-3.3.5 dll64\\ShapeDescriptor.exe --in file --out nf")
```

Comment: Forget about subprocess for a minute, and imagine what you would do if you were just trying to construct a string including the file name.

Comment: I added something like file_name = os.path.join(root,file), then merged it with the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the values of `file` and `nf` to the system call. This might be the one you are looking for.

```
os.system("C:\\Users\\X\\Desktop\\fftw-3.3.5 dll64\\ShapeDescriptor.exe --in {0} --out {1}".format(file,nf))
```

Comment: I changed the last line but still couldn't get the results

Comment: I understand the problem, because there are whitespaces in input files...